# is this the way to evaluate these functions? if not, how can I evaluate?

Tags: functions

Given that $$
f(x)=1-x,  g(x)=x^2-3, h(x)=\frac2x
$$

1) Find $$f\,o\,g$$

My answer 1) $$f\,o\,g(x)=f(g(x))=f(x^2)=3x^2-1$$
2) Find   $$f\,o\,h$$
My answer 2)  $$f\,o\,h = f(h(x))= 2/1-x-3  $$
3) find $$f\,o\,g\,o\,h$$
My answer 3) $$f\,o\,g\,o\,h = (f(g(h(x)) = (x^2-3)(\frac2x = 1x^2-3-x, 1 \frac 2x$$
4) Find $$g\,o\,f$$
My answer 4) $$g\,o\,f=g(f(x))=(1-x)=1^2-x-3$$
5) Find $$h\,o\,h$$
My answer 5) $$h\,o\,h= h(h(x))=h(\frac 2x=2(\frac 2x)/x = 4x/x$$ 
6) Given f(x)=3x-2. if f(2k)=9k-11, find the value of k.

Comment: Your post is taking almost half of the page. :)

Comment: would I rather ask 1 by 1?

Comment: I don't know what is suitable. :)

Answer (score 1):

you are dazzled by all the $x$'s! in defining a function, $x$ is used as a *bound variable*. think of it like this:
$$
f: x \to 1-x \tag{1}
$$
$$
g: y \to y^2 -3 \tag{2}
$$
$$
h: z \to \frac2{z} \tag{3}
$$

now it is less confusing. suppose you want to find $h \circ g$. we look at the action of this function on $s$, say.
$$
h \circ g (s) = h(g(s)) \tag{4}
$$
to evaluate $h(g(s))$ we set $z=g(s)$ in equation (3):
$$
h(g(s)) = \frac2{g(s)} \tag{5}
$$
now set $y=s$ in equation (2), giving:
$$
g(s)=s^2 -3 \tag{6}
$$
using (6) we may rewrite (5) as
$$
h(g(s))= \frac2{s^2-3}
$$
so we have the result, expressed using $s$ for the bound variable as
$$
h \circ g: s \to \frac2{s^2-3}
$$
you may treat your examples in the same way. after a little practice you may often write the answer down without having to make all the steps explicit. for example it is easy to see that:
$$
g \circ h:u \to \frac4{u^2}-3
$$
there is no need to use a different letter as the bound variable every time. i have done it here to help you get things clear